# If an object accelerates more than $g$ (9.81m/s/s), wouldn't it weigh more than when it is at rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration

Weight is a force. Correctly measured in Newtons, not kilograms.
Weight is a product of mass times acceleration. That's Newton's Second Law.
Rest-weight is mass times $g$ the gravitational acceleration constant.
But if that object accelerated faster than $g$, wouldn't it weigh more than it would when it is not moving?

Comment: Weight means “how much force is gravity pulling on it with”. So if it is at rest, or in free fall, or being accelerated by some other force at a acceleration higher than $g$... it still has the same weight and is still being pulled on by gravity the same amount. If it is at rest, then gravity pulls on it, and something balances out gravity (like the normal force of the table it rests on). Because if not accelerating, then adding up all forces gives zero net force.

Comment: Take a bathroom scale into an elevator and witness what happens when you accelerate up and down.

Comment: Thanks Mr. White!

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably more a matter of terminology than actual physics.

I believe that you imagine a piece of matter falling with an acceleration that is higher than $g$ and if that can count as "more weight". If weight is defined as net force of object downwards towards earth then sure it has "more weight". However "weight" is usually defined as $mg$ meaning that it will have the same weight independently of other forces than gravity giving it a higher acceleration than g.